# Using a decimal addition table for subtracting

Tags: arithmetic

I'm reviewing the math I missed in school and I've come across a decimal addition table in a book along with a description of how to use the same table for subtracting. I'm having trouble parsing the description on how to subtract, though.

"The decimal addition table can also be used for subtraction! This is because subtraction is the inverse of addition. For example, to solve $9-7$, find the $7$ in the top row and drop down to the nine in the table. The difference, 2, is in the same row as nine on the left side of the table."

I'm overthinking it. It's a habit. Here's an image of the table:

[image: table]

Comment: Because you are finding the $?$ which fits $7+? = 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a diagram may help. Here is the table from your source with circles and arrows (but no paragraph on the back of it) showing the steps of the calculation.

[image]

When they say "drop down" they mean follow the downward-pointing arrow, and for "the same row as nine" they intend you to follow the left-pointing arrow.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you much!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute $ x = 9 - 7 $, but this is the same as finding $x$ that satisfies $x +7 = 9$.

Answer (score 0):

For adding

Sum = column of the first no.+ row of the second no.

Sum - column of the first no. = row of the second no.

For 9-7

So the large no. is the sum 9, small number is the column number, and corresponding row no. is the subtraction (column no. , row no. are equal to the first row and first columns respectively. )